# Ingress-Nginx rewrite service name based on path

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've seen many examples online of doing the following, straight from the [rewrite docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /something(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: http-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
```

However, we have an API that dynamically creates services, and would like to have a single ingress to manage them. All I'm asking is, does this work? Or something like it?

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: direct-to-service-by-name
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
        # Match any character but / and put it in capture group $1
      - path: /([^\/]+)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            # Name the service based on capture group 1
            name: $1
            port: 
              number: 80
```

Comment: I would "just try it" but I haven't gotten to access this layer of the networking stack yet. Just planning ahead.

Comment: If you want to capture the whole URI prefix maybe you need `^/([^/]+)` instead?

Comment: Sorry yes, forgot a +

Comment: You can "just try it" running something like [k3s](https://k3s.io/) locally. It doesn't require many resources and it lets you experiment with things like this very easily.

Comment: True. I'll self answer if I don't get a reply. Just haven't seen this discussed on the internet, maybe for the next person it will be googleable.

Comment: Hi Ryan, AFAIK this can be different depending on the nginx ingress version. Can you share which nginx ingress version are you using?

Comment: Let's just assume latest?   https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx ingress-ngix/ingress-nginx Chart version "4.0.16"